# How to access the object passed along with the event object in the fireBuy() method?

Tags: sapui5

```
<script>
        sap.ui.core.Control.extend("com.controls.MyButton", {
            metadata: {
                aggregations: {
                    buyButton : { type: "sap.ui.commons.Button", multiple: false}
                },
                events: {
                    buy: {enablePreventDefault: true}
                }
            },
            init: function() {
                var oControl = this;
                 //create a button to allow used buying that book
                var oBuyBtn = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Click Me",
                    press: function (oEvent) {
                        oControl.fireBuy({
                            someData : "some data I want to pass along with the event object"
                        });
                    }
                });
                this.setAggregation("buyButton", oBuyBtn);

            },
            renderer: {
                render: function(oRm, oControl) {
                    oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("buyButton"));
                }
            }
        });

        var oButton = new com.controls.MyButton({
            buy: function(oEvent) {
                alert(oEvent.someData);
            }
        });
        oButton.placeAt("content");
    </script>
```

The code is shown above. I want to get the someData property in the change callback function, How can I possibly achieve that? I tried oEvent.someData, but I got undefined alert. The code is from nabisoft website, but there has no explanation on how to access the object passed by the fireBuy method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var oButton = new com.controls.MyButton({
            buy: function(oEvent) {
                alert(oEvent.getParameter("someData"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

oEvent.getParamter("someData") solves this!